# Adding subscribers to a list using Mailchimp's API

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I just started this all API thing-
I'm trying to upload data to Mailchimp using their API.
I'm not getting any error while running my server, but the data won't get updated
(I do get the values from the html form and they get displayed in the hyper terminal)
that's my code

```
const bodyParser=require("body-parser");
const request=require("request");
const https=require("https");

const app=express();

app.use(express.static("public")); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.get("/",function(req,res)  
{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/signup.html");
});

app.post("/",function(req,res)  
{
    const firstName=req.body.Fname;
    const lastName=req.body.Lname;
    const email=req.body.email;

    console.log(firstName,lastName,email);

    const data=
        {
            members:[
                {
                    email_adress:email,
                    status:"subscribed",
                    merge_fields:
                        {
                            FNAME:firstName,
                            LNAME:lastName
                        }
                }
            ]
        };
    const jsonData=JSON.stringify(data);

    const url="https://us8.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/b8e36ded50"; 
    const options=
        {
            methods:"POST",
            auth:"lidor:56599763339503b7bac161913940d98d-us8" 
        }
    const request=https.request(url,options,function(response)
            {
                response.on("data",function(data)
                        {
                            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
                        })
            })
    request.write(jsonData);
    request.end();


});

app.listen(3000,function()
{
    console.log("server has started on port 3000");
});
```

please help me !!

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
var mailchimpInstance   = 'your_prefix_server',
    listUniqueId        = 'your_listId',
    mailchimpApiKey     = 'your_api_key';

app.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
    request
        .post('https://' + mailchimpInstance + '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' + listUniqueId + '/members/')
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8')
        .set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + new Buffer.from('any:' + mailchimpApiKey ).toString('base64'))
        .send({
          'email_address': req.body.email,
          'status': 'subscribed',
          'merge_fields': {
            'FNAME': req.body.firstName,
            'LNAME': req.body.lastName
          }
        })
            .end(function(err, response) {
              if (response.status < 300 || (response.status === 400 && response.body.title === "Member Exists")) {
                res.send('Signed Up!');
              } else {
                res.send('Sign Up Failed :(');
              }
          });
});
```

from https://www.codementor.io/@mattgoldspink/integrate-mailchimp-with-nodejs-app-du10854xp

also he uses "superagent" module instead of "request" module. It works!

Comment: Also REQUEST module is deprecated